# NullreferenceException - Object Reference is not set to an instance of a object

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I get the `Exception: Object Reference` is not set to an instance of object.

I have a Globalvariables class that stores one specifik string, if the string is called "OK", then I should be able to load the page, but if the string is "Invalid" I shouldn't be able to Load the page.

In my default page, I have the following Page_load method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var masterPage = Master;

    if (masterPage != null)
    {
        if (GlobalVariables.Data.StartsWith("OK"))
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
        else
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

If I write `GlobalGlobalVariables.Data == "OK"` it works fine, but if I write like the above i get the error.

Comment: Which means `GlobalVariables.Data` is null

Comment: Where do you initialize `GlobalVariables.Data`? Also, the `if` clause makes not much sense. Maybe you wanted to use the `as` operator to check if your master is a  certain  type use: `var masterPage = this.Master as MyMasterPage;`.

Comment: I think you are getting GlobalVariables.Data = Null so it works with "GlobalGlobalVariables.Data == "OK" condition.

Comment: Apparently `GlobalVariables.Data` is null (not set at this moment) - where/when do you load that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the value of `GlobalVariables.Data` is not getting set before the `Page_Load` or it does not have a default value.

Solution 1: Add a default value.

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    private static string _data;

    public static string Data
    {
        get { return _data ?? "Invalid"; }
        set { _data = value; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if(GlobalVariables.Data.Equals("Ok", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{

}
else
{

}
```

But it sounds like you want a flag, so why not use an `enum`?

Solution 2: Enum

```
public enum DataStatus
{
    Invalid,
    Ok
}

public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public DataStatus DataStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
if(GlobalVariables.DataStatus == DataStatus.Ok)
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: i tried this, and it worked, it seems like this was my problem. I actually just thought it could work on the page_load without setting it with a default value. thanks alot.

Comment: Well `string` is a reference type and all reference types have a default value of `null`. Accessing a method of a `null` object will throw a `NullReferenceException` because the object is uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that you didn't initialize the global variable "GlobalVariables.Data". The .NET compiler will automatically initialize it to null, which is why you're getting the null reference exception. == is a static method (refer back to the operator overload MSDN doc for more if you're curious), which is why it doesn't throw the exception.

This all being said, it seems more like you might want to be using a Boolean, not a string, in this case, but I'm not familiar with your use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change code a bit

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GlobalVariables.Data) && GlobalVariables.Data.StartsWith("OK"))
{
    //Do stuff
}
else
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

First check if your string is assigned to something ant then is it starts with OK symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You should refrain from using the "StartsWith" Method if the starts with part is your whole string. I would suggest doing something like this rather:

//this is a case-insensitive check of what the value *might* be

```
    if(!string.IsNullorEmpty(GlobalVariables.Data))
   {       
      if (GlobalVariables.Data.Equals("ok",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
       {
          //Do stuff
       }
    }
```